# What is the event for </body> loaded, not document loaded in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are many good practices with document loaded:

```
$(function(){
  ....
}
```

The code above seems to wait for some extra resources to be loaded to run. At least I am quite sure it's waiting for the Google Adsense content to be loaded.

But what about the `</body>` loaded? Because sometimes there's no need to wait for the document loaded. I just want to immediately work on the DOM that is loaded. Is there any event can do that?

Update:

The code is like this:

```
<script> 
  // The script tag has to be above the a tag - which will be worked on later.
</script>
<a id="tobeworkedon">test</a>
</body>
```

I can't just move the `script` tag to the latter part. Can I still make it as fast as it were right before the `</body>` tag?

Comment: Just load the script to the end of `body`, no need of any event.

Comment: What if the code HAS to be above the `</body>` due to some design reason?

Comment: That _is_ the event of the document having loaded. The other thing would be the event of all resources having loaded.

Comment: "DOM ready" basically IS "when the `</body>` tag has been read"... isn't it?

Comment: It seems it's waiting for some resources.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Why exactly can't the script tag be just before the `</body>`? I can't think of any design reason.

Comment: because the <a> tag is dynamically injected into the page and it can only be injected before </body>.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    ....
}
```

This method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's DOM becomes safe to manipulate.

Simply if the browser supports, you can use

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func, false);
```

For older browsers, you can try

```
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", func);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe is this what you looking:

```
<body onload="myFunction()"></body>
```

But notice: It will fire uppon body loading, even if some images or resources are not loaded yet.

Comment: I’m afraid that’s not true. `onload` will wait for all resources to be loaded. `DOMContentLoaded` (or jQuery’s `ready`) will wait until the document itself is loaded.

Comment: As I see, the body onload will fire even if a css/js resource from head is not loaded yet, am I wrong?

Comment: No. It waits for _all_ resources that are initially fetched on page load. Resources that are fetched later via AJAX can come after the `load` event. But that’s not really relevant. `load` will always come after `DOMContentLoaded` and `DOMContentLoaded` is the event used for `</body>` (or `</html>`, actually) to be loaded, i.e. for manipulating the DOM.